# Sequence of continuous functions on [0,1] converging to unbounded function.

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

I'm working on problem 3 from Exercises 2E of Axler's "Measure, Integration and Real Analysis" which says: [image]

I thought of something like $f_n (x) = \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{n}}$ , but then this converges to $f(x) = 1/x$, which isn't defined at $x = 0$ so it is not a function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$. When I attempt to fix this I lose either the continuity of $f_n$ or the convergence to $f$.

I'd appreciate any insight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define

$$f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
n^2 x &0 \leq x \leq \frac 1n \\
\frac 1x &\frac 1n \lt x \leq 1.
\end{cases}$$

Then $f_n$ converges pointwise to $\frac 1x$ for $x \in (0, 1]$ and $\forall n~f_n(0)=0.$